# Activate virtualenv via os.system()

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, fabric, pip

I'm writing a Python-based shell script to boilerplate a Django app with virtualenv, pip, and fabric. Should be straightforward enough, but it appears that I'm not able to activate and run commands in the virtualenv through the shell script.

```
os.system('virtualenv %s --no-site-packages' % project_name)
os.system('source %s/bin/activate' % project_name)
os.system('easy_install pip')
```

When running, this errors out:

```
$ startproject+ -s false sample
New python executable in sample/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
/testing
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 0.4
Processing pip-0.4-py2.6.egg
pip 0.4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
error: /usr/local/bin/pip: Permission denied
```

Obviously the `source` line isn't being run, but why? Is it a concurrency/threading issue, or something deeper with virtualenv?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `os.system` call creates a new process.  You'll need to ensure that the `activate` and the `easy_install` are run in the same `os.system` or `subprocess` call.

Answer (score 11):

Each call to os.system runs the command in a new subshell, which has the same properties as the original python process.

Try putting the commands into one string separated by semicolons.

Answer (score 6):

Just don't use "source activate" at all. It does nothing but alter your shell PATH to put the virtualenv's bin directory first. I presume your script knows the directory of the virtualenv it has just created; all you have to do is call _virtualenv_dir_/bin/easy_install by full path. Or _virtualenv_dir_/bin/python for running any other python script within the virtualenv.

Answer (score 3):

You could also install virtualenvwrapper, and use the postmkvirtualenv hook. I use it to automatically bring in fresh copies of pip and IPython into virtualenvs I create (as I don't want it using my system IPython). I also use it to copy pythonw into the virtualenv, otherwise wx-based stuff won't work. Looks like this:

```
easy_install pip
pip install -I ipython
cd ~/bin
python install_pythonw.py ${VIRTUAL_ENV}
```