# Activate Virtual Environment and Install Packages via Script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I often find myself recreating file structures for Flask apps so I have decided to make a script to do all that for me. I would like the script to create all the folders I need as well as the files with some basic boilerplate, which it does, that part is working fine. However I would also like to create a virtual environment and install Flask to that environment. That is where I am encountering the problem. The script runs but it installs Flask to my system installation of Python.

I followed the advice in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691076/activate-virtualenv-via-os-system) but it's not working. I am running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS via crouton on a Chromebook.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from os import mkdir, chdir, getcwd, system
import sys

APP_NAME = sys.argv[1]
ROOT = getcwd()
PROJECT_ROOT = ROOT + '/' + APP_NAME

# dictionary represents folder structure. Key is the folder name and the value is it's contents
folders = {APP_NAME : {'app' : {'static': {'css' : '', 'img' : '', 'js' : ''}, 'templates' : ''} } }

def create_folders(dic):
    for key in dic:
        if isinstance(dic[key], dict):
            mkdir(key)
            prev = getcwd() + '/' + key
            chdir(prev)
            create_folders(dic[key])
        else:
            mkdir(key)

create_folders(folders)

chdir(PROJECT_ROOT)
open('config.py', 'a').close()

with open('run.py', 'a') as run:
    run.write("""stuff""")

with open('app/__init__.py', 'a') as init:
    init.write("""stuff""")

with open('app/views.py', 'a') as views:
    views.write("""stuff""")

open('app/models.py', 'a').close()

open('app/forms.py', 'a').close()
with open('app/templates/layout.html', 'a') as layout:
    layout.write("""stuff""")
system('chmod a+x run.py')
system('virtualenv venv')
system('. venv/bin/activate;sudo pip install flask')  # this does not seem to be working the way I am expecting it to
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your calls are not within the same console session and therefore the console environment is not as expected. I suggest to concatenate the related commands in one system call using subprocess.Popen like this (including suggestions by limasxgoesto0):

```
subprocess.Popen('virtualenv venv;source venv/bin/activate;pip install flask')
```

You should probably be using subprocess; os.system is deprecated.

Comment: 1. It's ```source venv/bin/activate```.  2. Just ```pip install flask```.  If you use sudo, it will install globally

Comment: Using `subprocess.Popen('virtualenv venv;source venv/bin/activate;pip install flask')` gives me `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Included suggestions by limasxgoesto0