# Python: How to script virtual environment building and activation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, setup-deployment

I would like to write a python script that does 3 things :

1. build a virtual environment  with python3
2. activate this new virtual env. ( bash: source myvirtenv/bin/acticate)
3. install packages with  a requirements.txt (bash:  pip install -r )

In my project I use  the normal virtualenviroment package . and  I have to do it   on   a Debian machine.

I tried to mimic the bash command with `os.system()`  but didn't make it with the code below.

```
import os
os.system('python3 -m venv test6_env')
os.system('source test6_env/bin/activate')
os.system('pip install -r requirements.txt --user')
```

Problem the virtualenv  will not activated and the requirements not installed.

Is there a easy trick to script in python this 3 stepy nicely ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activate virtualenv via os.system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691076/activate-virtualenv-via-os-system)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+subshell

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that `os.system('source test6_env/bin/activate')` activates the virtual environment only for the subshell spawned by this particular `os.system()` call, and not any subsequent ones. Instead, run all shell commands with a single call, e.g.

```
os.system('python3 -m venv test6_env && . test6_env/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt')
```

Alternatively, put your commands in a shell script and execute that with `os.system()` or, better yet, using a function from the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module, e.g.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('/path/to/script.sh', check=True)
```

Comment: Thank for for good explanation, it makes more sens now.  Nevertheless I got with your command line  'source: not found'.  Then I tried your  alternative with  putting the command 'source...... /bin/activate in a shell script .  And  I got the same error.  Manually  I have not problem to activate the virtualenv,.  An idea ?

Comment: Use `.` instead of `source`. `source` works in Bash, but not sh.

Answer (score 2):

I had to make one approach right now, so i will leave it here. You must have virtualenv installed. Hope helps someone :)

```
def setup_env():
    import virtualenv
    PROJECT_NAME = 'new_project'
    virtualenvs_folder = os.path.expanduser("~/.virtualenvs")
    venv_dir = os.path.join(virtualenvs_folder, PROJECT_NAME)
    virtualenv.create_environment(venv_dir)
    command = ". {}/{}/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt".format(virtualenvs_folder, PROJECT_NAME)
    os.system(command)
```

Comment: virtualenv has dropped support for create_enviroment method. Instead it should use the cli_run method. Link to the docs here: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#programmatic-api