# Module loading behavior in virtualenv differs depending on caller

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-2.x

I found some very strange python behavior that breaks my `virtualenv` set-up:

I have set up a virtual python2 environment to run a python2 script and created a wrapper like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import subprocess
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(subprocess.call('/path/to/venv/bin/python /path/to/python2script.py', shell=True))
```

so that calling the wrapper will call the python2 script using the virtual environment.

Calling this wrapper manually from the console (it is marked as executable) works as expected.

```sh
me@my_pc:/somewhere$ /path/to/the/wrapper
~ python2 script running as expected ~
```

Now I have a separate project (python3) which needs to call the python2 script, so I'd like to call the wrapper either with `subprocess.check_call('/path/to/the/wrapper', shell=True)` or `subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/the/wrapper'])`.

However, when my separate python3 project does the call, it fails with:

```
  File "/path/to/python2script.py", line 31, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 284
    class YAMLObject(metaclass=YAMLObjectMetaclass):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So apparently, now the python2 in the virtual environment tries to use my global dist-packages, which are python3, hence it crashes.

But if I check again from the console:

```sh
me@my_pc:/somewhere$ /path/to/venv/bin/python
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:39:04) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
>>> print(yaml.__file__)
/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/__init__.pyc
```

If I call the wrapper from an interactive python3 shell (with the same `subprocess.call()`) it also works.

Why does python load 'yaml' from the virtual environment when I call it from the console or when I directly call the wrapper, but when another python script calls the wrapper it will use `dist-packages`?
Could the other script somehow have messed with the search order in a way that affects the python installation in the virtual environment?

---

## Possible work-around:

While not an explanation for the behavior, I found a hack that seems to make it work.

I found that the paths to the different module locations are in `sys.path`, but not in `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` and are in the wrong order when called from the script (with global paths first). Changing the order and writing the result back to `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` seems to solve the issue.

```py
sys_path_venv = [p for p in sys.path if 'venv' in p]
sys_path_rest = [p for p in sys.path if not p in sys_path_venv]
sys.path = sys_path_venv + sys_path_rest
os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = os.pathsep.join(sys.path)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Activate virtualenv via os.system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691076/activate-virtualenv-via-os-system)

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Thanks, but as you can see, I'm not using `source venv/bin/activate` and don't have to because I'm calling the python installation inside the `venv` directly with `venv/bin/python`. It's all in one call, not in separate calls.

Comment: "*Why does python load 'yaml' from the virtual environment when I call it from the console or when I directly call the wrapper, but when another python script calls the wrapper it will use dist-packages?*" Because something in between sets `$PYTHONPATH`. Unset it before running `/path/to/venv/bin/python`. Unset it in the wrapper, e.g.

Comment: @Makx this is actually your problem and that's what I mean. Python is using environment variables to determine where to look for packages. `source venv/bin/activate` handles this. You are not using it, so your Python 2.7 interpreter lands in Python 3.x packages and breaks when importing yaml module from Python 3.x packages.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Thank you again for your comment.
However, that should not be necessary when calling the python installation in the venv directly. See the answer by Carl Meyer to the question you referred to, and also I'm able to call the wrapper from the console without activating the virtualenv and it works without problems.
Just to be sure I tested it with `source venv/bin/activate` as well but the problem is the same.

Comment: @phd Thank you for the comment.
The paths to the virtualenv site-package folders actually aren't in the `$PYTHONPATH` but are added to `sys.path` at runtime. I added some information on a work-around I found.

Comment: @Makx just change the last line of your wrapper script to `sys.exit(subprocess.call('. /path/to/venv/bin/activate && python /path/to/python2script.py', shell=True))`