# Install packages in venv environment using Python script

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I have a program that has to install Python packages into a virtual environment, which seemed like an easy enough task at first. All I had to do was call `os.system('./venv/scripts/activate)`. Unfourtunatly, this turned out to be a much more difficult task, since you can't activate a venv using os.system as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691076/activate-virtualenv-via-os-system). So I tried installing the packages directly in *venv/Lib/site-packages* using `os.system('pip install --target venv/Lib/site-packages -r requirements.txt')` One of the modules I have to install (Autobahn[twisted]) is throwing an error saying `ERROR: Can not execute setup.py since setuptools is not available in the build environment.` At this point, I'm not even sure if it's a problem with the venv, but any help would be appreciated!

Full code is:

```
    os.system('git clone https://github.com/user/repository.git')
    os.chdir('repository')
    os.system('python -m venv ./venv')
    os.system('pip install --target venv/Lib/site-packages -r requirements.txt')
```

I swapped out the user and repository name in the URL and code for privacy reasons.

I was expecting the program to install the packages successfully.

Comment: You don't need to activate to install. You can use `/path/venv/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`... However, I'd recommend you do this with a regular shell script, not Python to manage Python. According to the error, you need to install setuptools...

Comment: Oh yeah, that would make a lot more sense. I guess I didn't realize that I could do that at the time. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [OneCricketeer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75585708/install-packages-in-venv-environment-using-python-script#comment133353294_75585708), you can use the full python path instead of just `python`. Like this:

```py
import os

os.system('git clone https://github.com/user/repository.git')
os.chdir('repository')
os.system('python -m venv ./venv')
os.system('/path/to/the/venv/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt')
```

---

To solve the missing `setuptools`, install it via:

```py
os.system('python -m venv ./venv')  # create the venv
os.system('/path/to/the/venv/bin/python -m pip install setuptools')
```